# for each error with printing a list

Tags: java, foreach

I'm trying to write a for each loop to print the entries of a list.

Here is my first method:

```
public Staff() {
    staffList = new StaffMember[4];

    staffList[0] = new Executive("Sam", "123 Main Line",
            "555-0469", "123-45-6789", 2423.07);

    staffList[1] = new Employee("Carla", "456 Off Line",
            "555-0101", "987-65-4321", 1246.15);
    staffList[2] = new Employee("Woody", "789 Off Rocker",
            "555-0000", "010-20-3040", 1169.23);

    staffList[3] = new Hourly("Diane", "678 Fifth Ave.",
            "555-0690", "958-47-3625", 10.55);
}
```

Here is my for each loop, which is causing errors:

```
for (Iterator<String> i = staffList.iterator; i.hasNext();) {
    String item = i.next();
    System.out.println(item);
}
```

The error I'm getting is that staffList.iterator says "cannot find symbol"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`staffList` is an array.  You can't treat an array like an `Iterator`.

The [enhanced `for` statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) will work just fine with it, though:

```
for(StaffMember member : staffList) {
    System.out.println(member);
}
```

Note:  the type of element you're iterating over is the type defined in the array, not `String` or anything else.

If you want to learn about the specifics as to *why*, then feel encouraged to look [at the language specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2) for the enhanced `for` statement.

Answer (score 2):

`staffList` is an array. Arrays don't have iterators. If you want to use iterator, use a `Collection` (e.g. a `List`).

If you're iterating over a raw array, just do:

```
for ( StaffMember s : staffList ) {
  ...
}
```

Additionally, even if you were using a list, your iterator would be `Iterator<StaffList>`, not `Iterator<String>`